# My project Spring Boot problem in created Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi my simple Spring Boot Security project

My UserController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path= "/api")
@RequiredArgcContructor
public class UserController {

    
    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public String create(@RequestBody UserDTO userDto){
        return  userService.save(userDto);
    }

}
```

My UserService

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

 
    private  UserManager userManager;
    private  Mapper<UserDTO, UserEntity> userDTOUserMapper;

    public String save(UserDTO userDto) {
        return userManager.signUp(userDTOUserMapper.map(userDto));
    }

}
```

My UserManager

```
   package com.userlogintask.userlogintask.business;

import com.userlogintask.userlogintask.model.TokenEntity;
import com.userlogintask.userlogintask.model.UserEntity;
import com.userlogintask.userlogintask.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserManager implements UserDetailsService {

    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_msg="user with email %s not found";
   
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final TokenManager tokenManager;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_msg,email)));
    }


    public String signUp(UserEntity userEntity){
        boolean isExist =  userRepository.findByEmail(userEntity.getEmail()).isPresent();

        if(isExist){
            throw new IllegalStateException("email is already exists");
        }
        String encodePassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userEntity.getPassword());
        userEntity.setPassword(encodePassword);
        userRepository.save(userEntity);

        //TODO:Send confirmation token;
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        TokenEntity confirmationTokenEntity = new TokenEntity(
                token,
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15),
                userEntity
        );
        tokenManager.saveConfirmationToken(confirmationTokenEntity);

        //TODO:Send email

        return  token;
    }

    public int enableAppUser(String email) {
        return userRepository.enableUser(email);
    }

}
```

My Mapping Configuration

```
 @Configuration
public class ApiMappingConfig {

    //userDTO mapping user

    @Bean
    public Mapper<UserDTO, UserEntity> userDTOUserMapper(){
        return Mapping.from(UserDTO.class)
                .to(UserEntity.class)
                .omitInDestination(UserEntity::getLocked)
                .omitInDestination(UserEntity::getUser_id)
                .omitInDestination(UserEntity::getEnabled)
                .mapper();
    }
}
```

My UserEntity

```
 @Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class UserEntity implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id",unique = true)
    private Long user_id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole userRole;

    private Boolean locked = false;
    private Boolean enabled = false;

    public UserEntity(String firstName,
                      String lastName, String email,
                      String password, UserRole userRole) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

}
```

My UserDTO

```
  @Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDTO {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private UserRole userRole;

}
```

My Main Class

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class UserlogintaskApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserlogintaskApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My Error

> Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file
> [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Java\userlogintask\target\classes\com\userlogintask\userlogintask\controller\UserController.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file
> [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Java\userlogintask\target\classes\com\userlogintask\userlogintask\service\UserService.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'userDTOUserMapper' defined in class path
> resource
> [com/userlogintask/userlogintask/mapping/ApiMappingConfig.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.remondis.remap.Mapper]: Factory method
> 'userDTOUserMapper' threw exception; nested exception is
> com.remondis.remap.MappingException: The get-method for property
> 'enabled' in type com.userlogintask.userlogintask.model.UserEntity is
> not a valid Java Bean property.   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]    at
> com.userlogintask.userlogintask.UserlogintaskApplication.main(UserlogintaskApplication.java:14)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file
> [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Java\userlogintask\target\classes\com\userlogintask\userlogintask\service\UserService.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'userDTOUserMapper' defined in class path
> resource
> [com/userlogintask/userlogintask/mapping/ApiMappingConfig.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.remondis.remap.Mapper]: Factory method
> 'userDTOUserMapper' threw exception; nested exception is
> com.remondis.remap.MappingException: The get-method for property
> 'enabled' in type com.userlogintask.userlogintask.model.UserEntity is
> not a valid Java Bean property.   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   ... 25 common frames omitted Caused
> by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'userDTOUserMapper' defined in class path
> resource
> [com/userlogintask/userlogintask/mapping/ApiMappingConfig.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.remondis.remap.Mapper]: Factory method
> 'userDTOUserMapper' threw exception; nested exception is
> com.remondis.remap.MappingException: The get-method for property
> 'enabled' in type com.userlogintask.userlogintask.model.UserEntity is
> not a valid Java Bean property.   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   ... 39 common frames omitted Caused
> by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.remondis.remap.Mapper]: Factory method
> 'userDTOUserMapper' threw exception; nested exception is
> com.remondis.remap.MappingException: The get-method for property
> 'enabled' in type com.userlogintask.userlogintask.model.UserEntity is
> not a valid Java Bean property.   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   ... 53 common frames omitted Caused
> by: com.remondis.remap.MappingException: The get-method for property
> 'enabled' in type com.userlogintask.userlogintask.model.UserEntity is
> not a valid Java Bean property.   at
> com.remondis.remap.MappingException.notAProperty(MappingException.java:55)
> ~[remap-4.2.5.jar:4.2.5]  at
> com.remondis.remap.MappingConfiguration.getPropertyDescriptorOrFail(MappingConfiguration.java:574)
> ~[remap-4.2.5.jar:4.2.5]  at
> com.remondis.remap.MappingConfiguration.getPropertyFromFieldSelector(MappingConfiguration.java:550)
> ~[remap-4.2.5.jar:4.2.5]  at
> com.remondis.remap.MappingConfiguration.omitInDestination(MappingConfiguration.java:117)
> ~[remap-4.2.5.jar:4.2.5]  at
> com.userlogintask.userlogintask.mapping.ApiMappingConfig.userDTOUserMapper(ApiMappingConfig.java:23)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.userlogintask.userlogintask.mapping.ApiMappingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$952967e9.CGLIB$userDTOUserMapper$0()
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.userlogintask.userlogintask.mapping.ApiMappingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$952967e9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7199a018.invoke()
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]    at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]     at
> com.userlogintask.userlogintask.mapping.ApiMappingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$952967e9.userDTOUserMapper()
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   ... 54 common frames omitted
> Process finished with exit code 0

My Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.userlogintask</groupId>
    <artifactId>userlogintask</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>userlogintask</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.20</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.remondis</groupId>
            <artifactId>remap</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What is the problem ? I am dont understand

Comment: Please post the project structure: in which package do you have `@SpringBootApplication` (main method) where is the service, Mapper, Manager and this controller. What is Mapper? Are you using some thirdparty or its your custom mapping code? Also please post the whole exception in the question, because currently its impossible to understand what happens exactly. Of course `userService` bean can't be created but why? To answer that we need this information

Comment: Okay Mark  not problem

Comment: @Zaur cretion of mapping failed - isolate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like the error is:

```
.MappingException: The get-method for property 'enabled' in type com.userlogintask.userlogintask.model.UserEntity is not a valid Java Bean property. at
```

That's why the mapper can't be created as it needs to, and this in turn causes the `BeanInitializationException` of the service.

Looking at your entity, you use:
`Boolean` for `enabled` property, but the getter returns `boolean` (not a wrapper class but a real primitive). Try to change that and see what happens.

Now I haven't worked with Mappers so I can't really comment on the semantics of `omitInDestination` method that you call while creating the mapper. However I think you can place a breakpoint and make sure that spring initializes the mapper out of your configuration, kind of generic "common sense" advice.